# Application error on deploy heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app is works fine in localhost, but when i deploy to heroku and try create a new order i receive this error:

```
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/orders/new" for 189.44.29.3 at 2013-03-20 21:26:02 +0000
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered orders/new.html.erb within layouts/application (49.4ms)
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (/app/app/views/orders/new.html.erb:31: unknown regexp options - tabl
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/orders/new.html.erb:33: unterminated string meets end of file
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/views/orders/new.html.erb:33: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end):
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:       <td><%= order.select :drop,options_for_select({"Nao",false,"Sim",true}) %></td>
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:   </tr>
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:   </tbody>
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     31: </table>
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     32:   <%= order.submit "Criar nova Compra !"%>
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     33: <% end %>
2013-03-20T21:26:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:16:in `new'
```

in my view have this code:

```
<%= form_for @order do |order| %>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Fornecedor</td>
        <td>Produto</td>
        <td>Quantidade</td>
        <td>Nr Compra</td>
        <td>Pagamento</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Endereço</td>
        <td>Dropship</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= order.select :seller,Place.all.map { |a| [a.place,a.place] }%></td>
        <td><%= order.select :product_id,Product.all.map { |a| [a.name,a.id] } %></td>
        <td><%= order.text_field :quantity,:size => 4 %></td>
        <td><%= order.text_field :order_number,:size => 2%></td>
        <td><%= order.select :payment,Place.all.map { |a| [a.place,a.place] }%></td>
        <td><%= order.text_field :value,:size => 5 %></td>
        <td><%= order.select :adress_id,Adress.all.map { |a| [a.name,a.id] }%></td>
        <td><%= order.select :drop,options_for_select({"Nao",false,"Sim",true}) %></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    <%= order.submit "Criar nova Compra !"%>
<% end %>
```

if someone can help me whit this i thanks, this erro happening when i try create a new order, thanks

i try whit the options_for_select and whitout, all cases i get this error in heroku !

Comment: Line 28 on your stacktrace is different from your view's code. Have you deployed your app with that change?

Comment: Its correct, i change many times to try work, but no the error persists, now is correct.This code works in localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your view. My best guess is that for your case, is that the following line

```
<td><%= order.select :drop,options_for_select({"Nao",false,"Sim",true}) %></td>
</tr>
```

may be rewritten as:

```
<td><%= order.select :drop,options_for_select({"Nao" => false, "Sim" => true}) %></td>
</tr>
```

The expression `{"Nao",false,"Sim",true}` has no meaning in default Ruby syntax.

Changing to this `{"Nao" => false,"Sim" => true}` will produce a hash.

Changing to this `["Nao",false,"Sim",true]` will produce an array.

According to the docs, the rails method [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) will accept either a hash or an array (or any enumerable type).